# Set conditions on anchor tag using php

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I am working in Wordpress and I need to set a condition on an anchor tag to force two pages to be viewed in sequential order.  It's a custom WooCommerce shopping process and the user must choose a size before choosing a certain subscription plan.

I'm trying to avoid the user missing a step out in the process and receiving the incorrect products.

I'm not a PHP programmer, so I'm doing my best with this and struggling.  I have done my research from other posts and this is how far I have got.

Can anyone help me finish this off please?

```
<?php 

$myurl = getUrl()
$buy = Url(/buy) 

if ( $myurl == "/shop" )

return $buy;

else 

echo '<p> You have to go to Page 1 first</p>';

?>

 <a href="<?php ???? ?>" class="button">Link</a>
```

Comment: I'm a little confused on what you're trying to accomplish with the `<a href`...

Comment: Where is `$myurl` defined? Or do you mean `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`

Comment: @Xorifelse Good spot. I didn't copy and past everything I had.  I've added it all now.

Answer (score 0):

How about just `<a href="<?php print $myurl; ?>Link</a>`

You just need to echo/print the string representation that you want to display.

Comment: "One word: No. Wait, that's 3 and now that's 12 in this string alone." More information is needed to provide an answer.

Comment: The button class should not be there. Apologies, I cut and pasted a link and missed it.  I want to add the link to an image.  The idea is to choose one of 3 size images (small, medium and large) and then choose 1 of 4 monthly plans on the next page.  I don't want users to be able to choose the plan without selecting a size first.  So, I would like the image links to have some sort of condition on them so they are active if the user has come from the page with the size images on, otherwise I would like a message to tell the user to go to the size page first.  Does that make sense?

Comment: The only way to tell if a user has gone to the previous page and selected an answer is either --

1. Use $_SESSION storage so if they refresh/move around you still know they've been there.
2. Save it to a database somewhere and check if it's there.

Comment: Ok; thanks. I'll, look into sessions.  The db is not going to be a practical option.

Comment: You can add it to the session easily with $_SESSION['something'] = $something; then when they hit the page check if that variable in the session is correct. If it's not then redirect them to the appropriate page etc.